# remove index.php from url with two parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have the two following URL like below

www.site.com/index.php?key=blah

www.site.com/index.php?key=blah&pass=blahblah

I want to make it like the following using .htaccess

www.site.com/blah/blahblah
www.site.com/blah

in same webpage

How can i achieve this using .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?key=$1&pass=$2
```

should do it.

**Edit:** If you want the parameters optional, use this one.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$   /index.php?key=$1
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(([^/]+)?)$   /index.php?key=$1&pass=$2
```

I simply added a new rule where only one parameter is required. It does match first when only one parameter is given. If two parameters a given the second rule matches only.

Comment: Some time the single parameter i want to use  www.site.com/index.php?key=blah then it is not working